# Using CATransition's In Three20?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, catransition, ttnavigator

I am looking to implement CATransitions within TTNavigator, I know the method
openURL can take a UIViewAnimationTransition but that only gives me
flipping and curling animations, but with CATransition I have access
to another 8, of which kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromLeft,
kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom are the ones I am
specifically after.

With a UINavigationController would use something like this piece of code to
give me more control over the animation:

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
    forKey:nil];
```

This code however, doesn't work with TTNavigator. Does anybody know
how I can get my own custom animations to work with TTNavigator? Or if
I am doing something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out i answered my own question, but rather than using that last line of code to set the animation on the navigationController i was trying to set the transition to the URLAction. Once i put that line back in and commented out the URLAction transition code it seems to work!

```
    // create the URLAction
TTURLAction* urlAction;
urlAction = [TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://Images"]; 
[urlAction applyAnimated:YES];

    // create the CATransition and set it to the navigation controller
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
forKey:nil]; 

    // tell the navigator to run the action
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:urlAction];
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add flip or any other kind of animation on TTNavigator using TTLauncherView as follows:

```
- (void)launcherView:(TTLauncherView*)launcher didSelectItem:(TTLauncherItem*)item {
    TTURLAction* action = [TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:item.URL];
    [action setAnimated:YES];
    [action setTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];
    [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:action];
}
```

This makes TTNavigator use animated transition while displaying new URL.